# Laravel prepared statements UPDATE Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to update a database row but I want to prevent sql injection

```
$postdata = $request->except('token');
$src = json_decode($postdata['data']);

$locationData = addslashes ( $src->locationData );
$userData = addslashes ( $src->userData );
if ( isset($src->routeData) ){
    $routeData = addslashes ( $src->routeData );
} else {
    $routeData = null;
}
$url = addslashes ( $src->url );

DB::statement("UPDATE maps SET locationData = '$locationData', userData = '$userData', routeData = '$routeData' WHERE url = ?", [$url]);
```

I would be very greatful if someone were to show me in the above how to secure the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

safest way is to use model:

models/Map.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Map extends Model {
    protected $table = 'maps'
}
```

and in Your code:

```
$url = 'blabla';
$locationData = 'dadada';
$userData = 'nomnomnom';

Map::where('url', '=', $url)->update(compact('locationData', 'userData'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't wish to use a model, then you can simply use `DB::statement()` as it already uses prepared statements by default.

Therefore, it is not necessary for you to `addslashes`.

```
$postdata = $request->except('token');
$src = json_decode($postdata['data']);

$locationData = $src->locationData;
$userData = $src->userData;
if ( isset($src->routeData) ){
    $routeData = $src->routeData;
} else {
    $routeData = null;
}
$url = $src->url;

DB::statement("UPDATE maps SET locationData=?, userData=?, routeData=? WHERE url=?",
 [$locationData, $userData, $routeData, $url]);
```